# Uploading files on Amazon EC2

Tags: macos, amazon-ec2, terminal

I have an Amazon EC2 instance running. When i access the url, I get the Apache Test page, and it says that i'll have to upload my files into `/var/html/`

My question is, how do i do it? 
I use Mac OS X 's terminal for accessing the instance.

FTP doesn't seem to work. Is there any other way?

Comment: Follow this instructions if you use Cyberduck to connect : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hd4oL3WIPVM
And if you use FileZilla you can follow the instructions bellow: 
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=e9BDvg42-JI

Comment: Use the `aws` CLI tool provided by Amazon described in [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/664741/182460).

Answer (score 73, accepted):

If you're using a Mac (or other *nix system), simply copy-paste this to terminal to upload a file via SSH

```
scp -i MyKeyFile.pem FileToUpload.pdf ubuntu@ec2-123-123-123-123.compute-1.amazonaws.com:FileToUpload.pdf
```

replace "ec2-123-123-123-123.compute-1.amazonaws.com" with your instance's public DNS name

Comment: Great stuff! Solved my problem quickly

Comment: I've used your command and upload the file successfully. But now, where is my file? I can't find it on the server! o.O

Comment: SOLVED: they are uploaded into ~/home/ec2-user

Comment: Thanks!
`scp -i MY_PPK-FILE.pem.txt FILE ec2-user@MY_EC2_PUBLIC-IP:FILE`

Comment: what if he is on windows :/

Comment: Is it the same for copying a set of files or a complete local folder to AWS EC2??

Answer (score 16):

You actually shouldn't use FTP to access [Amazon EC2](http://aws.amazon.com/ec2/) instances at all (or any other server for that matter, but that's a different issue, see the slightly exaggerated, but nonetheless appropriate rant [FTP Must Die](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/FtpMustDie)).

Rather, you should use the [SSH File Transfer Protocol (SFTP)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SSH_File_Transfer_Protocol), which usually works just fine on EC2 instances out of the box without requiring additional security settings outside of SSH access in place anyway, i.e. since you already have access via your SSH keys you can use these as well for SFTP with your favorite (S)FTP client.

#### (S)FTP security

Even more important than this out of the box support without additional security/firewall settings is that SFTP is **secure**, while FTP is exactly the opposite, see e.g. [What's Your Password? xyzzy? Great!](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/FtpMustDie#What.27s_Your_Password.3F__xyzzy.3F__Great.21):

> As stated earlier, FTP predates the age when Internet activity was
>   expected to be malicious. As such, **it has no provisions for security
>   against password sniffing, man in the middle attacks, and so on**.
>
> **Your username and password are transmitted *in the clear* from the FTP
>   client to the FTP server.** Anyone with control over any of the routers
>   along the path from client to server can read the entire session,
>   including your password. *[emphasis mine]*

Please note that this can be remedied to some extend by using [FTP over SSL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FTPS) or [FTP over SSH](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FTP_over_SSH#FTP_over_SSH_.28not_SFTP.29), but both requires additional work and provide no benefits over SFTP for regular use cases like yours.

#### (S)FTP clients

Nowadays most FTP clients should support SFTP as well one way or another, ideally facilitating an *SSH authentication agent* like [ssh-agent](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ssh-agent) (Unix/Linux/Mac OS X) or [Pageant (Putty)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PuTTY#Applications) (Windows) to avoid the need to explicitly specify the SSH key to use (though that's possible as well of course).

There are likely plenty of SFTP clients for Mac OS X, a free one is [Cyberduck](http://cyberduck.ch/), which is a *[Libre](http://www.gnu.org/philosophy/free-sw.html) FTP, SFTP, WebDAV & cloud storage browser for Mac & Windows* (see their [SFTP Howto](http://trac.cyberduck.ch/wiki/help/en/howto/sftp)).

Comment: This is all well and good, but it doesn't really address any of the specifics of working in EC2, which I would expect given the original question.

Answer (score 4):

You can try [kitten](https://github.com/hoffa/kitten) utility which is a wrapper around boto3. You can easily upload/download files and run commands on EC2 server or on multiple servers at once for that matter.

```
kitten put -i ~/.ssh/key.pem cat.jpg /tmp [SERVER NAME][SERVER IP]
```

Where server name is e.g `ubuntu` or `ec2-user` etc.

This will upload `cat.jpg` file to `/tmp` directory of server

Answer (score 0):

Sorry. none of the answer helped me..but i learnt from the answers. What helped me is that i was using the wrong security keyname.

Usesful Tips:

- 1)if you have multiple security keys (.pem files), check your AWS
  account with Key pair name
- 2) Check the order of your SCP command
  parameters.
- 3) check if, “ubuntu” has the permission to write in the
  target directory.

Answer (score 0):

This might be a bit late, but I would recommend using the program Filezilla.
It has a very user-friendly interface and lets you move files and folders from one server to the other, or your local machine with drag and drop. Granted it's not as fast as using the terminal but it's the newbie must-have tool.
Also, it's free, but if you really like it pay the 10 bucks it costs and support your free-ware developers. I did
Its for Mac and can be found in the app store.

Answer (score -1):

The easiest way is to install webmin and user the file manager (java plugin) from your browser.

//Go to home folder

```
cd ~
```

//Download the latest version

```
wget http://prdownloads.sourceforge.net/webadmin/webmin-1.660-1.noarch.rpm
```

//install

```
sudo rpm -U webmin-1.660-1.noarch.rpm
```

//Change default password of root user

```
passwd
```

Finally, open port 10000 in the security groups

Then, log into

```
https://server_name:10000
```

with user:root password:what_you_set_before