# how can i upload files to EC2 amazon in MAC

Tags: amazon-ec2

I have created an EC2 instance in amazon , But i have no idea how to upload files in it, I use mac , so some one please guide me, their document did not help me .

Comment: hmm -1 ?? i am noob so i get it :(

Comment: you may want to read : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10364950/uploading-files-on-amazon-ec2

Comment: i read it, i swear i cant understand a bit !! what i know is terminal and how to connect to a server via ssh

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What is the operating system of the instance?

If it is a linux machine then you can use scp:
`scp -i  key.pem somefile.txt root@someip.compute-1.amazonaws.com:/tmp/`

For Windows this might help:
http://haacked.com/archive/2010/05/17/remote-desktop-file-copy.aspx

Comment: yea linux, how can i do this??should i connect via terminal in mac??if so how?

Comment: Yes, you could use the terminal. Do you have the .pem file?

Comment: i used the code scp -i key.pem index.html root@ec2-50-17-88-32.compute-1.amazonaws.com:/tmp/ and i used amazon linux

Comment: You should change the file permissions for the key file:
chmod 400 key.pem

Comment: ok i changed , now i got this error Please login as the ec2-user user rather than root user.

Comment: Change the user from "root" to "ec2-user": scp -i key.pem index.html ec2-user@ec2-50-17-88-32.compute-1.amazonaws.com:/tmp/

Comment: yea i uploaded :) , how can i access it ? ec2-50-17-88-32.compute-1.amazonaws.com is not accessible

Comment: You would need to setup an http server for that to work. Check out: http://codingthis.com/web/how-to-host-simple-content-with-amazon-elastic-cloud-computing-ec2/