# how do i determine s3 bucket name given existing mount point

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-ec2

I've inherited an already configured ec2 instance and am trying to download data from it.

I have set up S3Browser with relevant credentials but just need the name of the external bucket to connect to.

I can ssh to the machine and see that the bucket with the data is already mounted - thusly *some numbers changed to protect the innocent..

```
df

/dev/sda1            123234234  123234234  123234234  23% /
/dev/sda2            123234234  123412341  123234234  91% /mnt
/dev/sdh             123234234  123234234  123234234  62% /ebs
```

But what I need is the *name* of the bucket for - say the /ebs mount point - to enter into s3browser.

I realise this is kind of going backwards... but there must be a way. If not where can I find information on available s3 buckets?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might eventually be confusing a few AWS concepts, at least the information you provided seems to be inconsistent with your question at first sight.

While it is indeed possible to mount an [Amazon S3](http://aws.amazon.com/s3/) bucket on an [Amazon EC2](http://aws.amazon.com/ec2/) instance (see e.g [s3fs](https://code.google.com/p/s3fs/), which is a *FUSE-based file system backed by Amazon S3*), the name of the mount point in question suggests that this is an [Amazon Elastic Block Store (EBS)](http://aws.amazon.com/ebs/) volume instead. If that would be the case, you can only access the data via the EC2 instance where the volume is attached to and not via external tools.

- Please also note that while it is possible to create point-in-time *Snapshots* of EBS volumes (see [Key Features of EBS Volumes](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/AmazonEBS.html#EBSFeatures)), which are indeed persisted to S3, this operation is outside of your control and entirely handled by EC2, see the respective [FAQ Will I be able to access my snapshots using the regular Amazon S3 APIs?](http://aws.amazon.com/ec2/faqs/#Will_I_be_able_to_access_my_snapshots_using_the_regular_Amazon_S3_APIs):

> No, snapshots are only available through the Amazon EC2 APIs.
>   
>   As for your subsequent question *where can I find information on available s3 buckets*:

This is most easily done via the [AWS Management Console](http://aws.amazon.com/console/), which allows you to *Access and manage Amazon Web Services through a simple and intuitive web-based user interface*.

Comment: thanks for this - ok so I see i am confused.. you are right that the data is in ebs. I guess i want to get data from ebs out of Amazon and down to my local machine. To do this I have to *create* an s3 bucket, mount it to the ec2 instance then copy the data from ebs into the bucket and from there down to my local machine? Holy moly that's complicated is it not?

Comment: @utunga - alternatively you might want to reuse your SSH credentials to access the instance via [SSH File Transfer Protocol (SFTP)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SSH_File_Transfer_Protocol); most FTP programs support this these days, good ones are e.g. [WinSCP](http://winscp.net/eng/index.php), [Cyberduck](http://cyberduck.ch/) or [Filezilla](https://filezilla-project.org/).

Comment: again, thanks for the comments Stefan. I have found out earlier on that the same credentials file approach that works just fine with ssh is not working with scp. when i try to transfer even the smallest file I get a 'Permission Denied' error. From what i've read elsewhere amazon doesn't allow scp - hence the existence of things like s3cmd ? But perhaps I'm still confused. have you or has anyone successfully used scp or sftp with amazon s3 accounts connecting offsite ?

Comment: @utunga - SCP/SFTP support has nothing to do with AWS, the earlier [SCP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secure_copy) and its successor [SFTP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SSH_File_Transfer_Protocol) differ significantly though; each can be disabled/enabled separately within the typical SSH daemon, but I haven't encountered a situation where SFTP didn't just work out of the box for quite a while (mostly Ubuntu 12.04, see also my related answer to [Uploading files on Amazon EC2](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10365856/45773)) - given you _inherited_ the instance, it might just be disabled there?

Comment: @utunga - You are indeed still messing services up a bit btw., I suggest to make yourself familiar with these: [Amazon S3](http://aws.amazon.com/s3/) is _storage for the Internet_. You need a dedicated S3 client to interact with this, this has nothing to do with (S)FTP - nowadays many former (S)FTP only programs have support for the S3 API build in as well though. [Amazon EC2](http://aws.amazon.com/ec2/) is _a web service that provides resizable compute capacity in the cloud_, i.e. it provides virtual machines with your choice of OS (Windows/Unix/Linux/...).